# Send Location Updates to Server in Background

Tags: android, ios, flutter

What is the best way to keep user's location in sync with server,even after the app is terminated?
here is what I found this far

1. using a foreground service. I already tested that but it's battery consuming, and sometimes it's killed when you lock the phone or turn off the screen.
2. using work manager. I also tested it, it sends the location every 15 mins,but so unreliable, and it stopped sending after a while.
3. Geofencing. I read that Geofencing api gets location updates more often, every couple of minutes or so, but I haven't tested it.
4. LocationListener. There is a method called onLocationChanged, but I don't know how would it work in background.

is there something like a broadcast receiver that will be fired only when location changed by a margin? I think this would be an optimized solution.
I am building an app that uses a feature similar to facebook nearby friends (which is stopped working long time ago) or something like tinder to display nearby people.
Currently I need this for android, but I will need it for IOS as well, I am developing a flutter app.

Comment: It seems like a privacy concern that you want to keep getting updates on the user location, even when the app is not in the foreground... I bet newer version of Android will not allow you to do that sort of thing regardless.

Comment: how does tinder do that? It shows you the people around you with their distance from you

Comment: Well I'm no Tinder and I've barely used it, but I would say it only does that while you're INSIDE the app (or the app is in the foreground).  What I would do, instead of prying at the user's location 100% of the time, is that I would query for their location as soon as they open your app and do whatever you need with it, and save it somewhere.  Once they close the app, you can used the cached location info to keep doing your thing, if necessary. Though that second part still sounds like a privacy concern to me tbh.  If it helps, please let me write it down as an answer for you to accept!

Comment: While you do need to consider the privacy aspects they are independent of the technical aspect of this question. On iOS your app can get the users location with an "always" permission if the user allows. If your app is terminated by the user then you won't get updates since they killed your app and iOS assumes they wanted it dead. On iOS your best approach is probably to use significant location change updates. This is battery friendly but only gives you updates every 500m or so. Make sure you also read up on how iOS uses "provisional always" to initially only provide foreground location

Comment: After some time the user is asked if they want to also provide their location to your app when it is in the background. You may need to look at Android separately as I don't know how that platform handles location updates

Comment: @IvanGarza I never used tinder either but it came up when I was looking for a method to share location, and after looking into it, it turned out that it updates the location only when you open the app, just as you suggested, I think I will stick with the background service and the user opening the app. But you can write me an example of your idea and I may accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really have an example, as I'm not entirely familiar with those APIs all that much.  I can write out the theory as we discussed with some pseudo code as examples.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, I will read about it, but if I can't access location when the app is closed, what does "always" mean? Like in background but not terminated(swiped away)?

Comment: There are four main states for an iOS app - "running in the foreground", "suspended", "running in the background" and "terminated". When you say "closed" you probably mean "suspended" (ie the user has moved another app to the foreground). An app can move from suspended to running in the background in specific case for short durations; receiving a location update is one of those (assuming you have the user's permission).

Comment: An app moves from suspended to terminated in two ways; one is when it has been suspended for some time and iOS needs memory. The other is if the user swipes up to terminate the app. Significant location updates can relaunch your app from the first case but not if the user terminated your app.

Comment: You can get background location updates on Android. There are [limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits). The default behaviour is similar to iOS's significant location change with a few updates per hour. You can start a foreground service, with user permission and which will show in the notification area, to get more frequent updates.

Comment: On iOS side, see [Handling Location Events in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background/), focusing on significant change service. FWIW, I think that users are more skeptical about allowing apps to track them after reports [of the systematic abuse of location data](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/12/10/business/location-data-privacy-apps.html).

Answer (score 1):

I already used a similar method in my app which is working:

I used foreground service to record the location, the battery consumptions are related to the frequency of location request not really the foreground service itself. indeed using LocationListener is a good option

then I am checking the foreground service regularly using workmanager and restart it when needed.

best

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in the comments above, I don't really think Android allows for you to get location updates in the background even when the application is not active.

I recommend you instead try to query for location as soon as the app starts, and quickly follow up with whatever actions you need to make with it.  As an option, you can also keep track of location history by caching their location as they interact with the app, in case you want to keep the database as fresh as possible.

Here's some pseudo code as a simple example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(..) {
   queryForLocation(..)?.let {
      doSomething(it)
      cacheLocation(it)
   } ?: Log.d(TAG, "Location = null")
}

override fun onDestroy() {
   queryForLocation(..)?.let {
      cacheLocation(it)
   } ?: Log.d(TAG, "Location = null")
}
```